# How do I define a Scheme procedure that takes a set (a list of distinct elements) and generates a list of all subsets of the set?

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

First off, I wanted to clarify that I understand that there are similar questions to what I am asking, but I have a very specific output case that I am trying to replicate.

I am trying to create a Scheme procedure that allows me to take a set and generate a list that shows all possible subsets of that set.

For example, if I call: `(subsets '(a b c ))` I should get: `'((a b c) (b c) (a c) (c) (a b) (b) (a) ())` (in that order specifically)

Here is what I have so far:

```
(define (subsets givenList)
  (if (null? givenList)
      (list null)
      (let ((rest (subsets (cdr givenList))))
        (append rest (map (lambda (x)
                            (cons (car givenList) x))
                          rest)))))
```

My output for this is: `(() (c) (b) (b c) (a) (a c) (a b) (a b c))` but that is not the specific output that I am looking for.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the logic of the required order?

Comment: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20622945/how-to-do-a-powerset-in-drracket/20623487#20623487).

Comment: @Barmar The order seems to be: all subsets containing `c` are first, followed by subsets containing `b` but not `c`, followed by subsets containing `a` but not `b` or `c`. Recursively, within the `c` subsets, those containing `b` are listed before those containing only `a`, and within those recursive `b` subsets, that containing `a` is listed before the one not containing `a`;  there is a kind of recursive right-to-left elimination rule going on.

Answer (score 1):

To obtain a list of all subsets of `'(a b c)`, in the desired order:

- First, as **induction hypothesis**, suppose that you have a list `R` with all subsets of `'(b c)` in the desired order, i.e., `R = '((b c) (c) (b) ())`.
- Then, **mapping** each sublist of `R` into another sublist starting with the element `a`, you can create the list `S = '((a b c) (a c) (a b) (a))`.
- Finally, you can **interleave** the elements of `S` and `R`, starting with the first element of `S`, to obtain the final list `'((a b c) (b c) (a c) (c) (a b) (b) (a) ())`.

```
(define (subsets L)
  (if (null? L)
      (list null)
      (let* [(R (subsets (cdr L)))
             (S (map (lambda (x) (cons (car L) x)) R))]
        (interleave S R))))

(define (interleave A B)
  (cond [(null? A) B]
        [(null? B) A]
        [else (cons (car A) (cons (car B) (interleave (cdr A) (cdr B))))]))
```

Example:

```
> (subsets '(a b c))
'((a b c) (b c) (a c) (c) (a b) (b) (a) ())
```